# Angular - Replace the Embedded tag with dynamic value

Tags: angular, string, interpolation, directive

I have a need where dynamic value needs to be replace with the static sentence coming from the backend with Embeede tags in line.

e.x. The Text is the below with "current date" which needs to be replace from API response with Value as mentioned in the Value Object.

Application Open date is ##CurrentDate##

Value:{
Key:"CurrentDate",
value:"10th September 2021"
}

Any Suggestion, how this can be achieved in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement the simple solution is you can achieve that with simple data binding. assign an initial value to the reference element and change the default value after receiving the API value like below.

```
public openDate = 'CurrentDate';
```

After receiving data just re-assign the value of the respective variable.

```
apicall.subscribe(data=>this.openDate=data.value);
```

If you need a generic solution go for the custom directive in angular. create your own custom directive and implement your logic.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[value-transform]'
})
export class ValueTransformDirective {
@Input() apiData: string;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if(apiData.value)
    this.elem.nativeElement.innerText=apiData.value;
   }
}
```

In your HTML file, you can access the custom directive like below

```
<div value-transform [apiData]="value">CurrentDate</div>
```

Make sure that you are passing the value in **[apiData]**